# Unable to get $settings['config_exclude_modules'] to work - am I misunderstanding how it works?

Tags: configuration

**Drupal 10 on Pantheon.**

We have our settings.php file updated with this line:

```
$settings['config_exclude_modules'] = ['devel', 'stage_file_proxy', 'status_messages'];
```

This line exists locally and also in Pantheon's environment settings.php files.

When we run the config sync from the menu UI: /admin/config/development/configuration

and click the "IMPORT ALL" button, we expect that the three modules above would remain disabled but they become enabled from the extensions config.

Am I misunderstanding how this works? What is the proper way to ignore specific module's enabled/disabled states during config sync?